# Hibernate HQL Query field of property

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Say I have three Entities in Java: Entity A, Entity B and Entity C. Entity A has Entity B as a field and Entity B has Entity C as a field. Now in my DAO class I am given an object of Entity C. Using a Hibernate HQL query, is it possible to update all instances of Entity A in the database that have an entity B, who in turn have their entity C field equal to the object of Entity C. Concretely, I envision something like the below. Is the following query possible? Note that I am using the ids to check for equality

```
C c = new C();
c.setId(someId);

Query query = session.createQuery("update A set someField = true where b.c=:c");
        query.setEntity("c", c);
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Is it possible to use join in the query?

Comment: what would your concrete solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

Joins are not supported in Hibernate bulk DML statements. You can use subqueries for this purpose. For example:

```
update A set someField = true
where id in (select id from A where b.c = :c)
```

Comment: are you sure this works? what is the difference between this statement and the statement above from me?

Comment: @KevinWu Do you try your code at all before shipping it? :) You did not tell us about the outcome of your original attempt either. Try it and come back to us with the results, otherwise it is impossible to guess what will be working in your application setup. Regarding the difference, implicit joins via navigation paths are translated to joins in the from clause.

Comment: true, I will give it a shot. BTW. We are currently not quite in a position to test  our code yet, but that time will come soon:)